# What is the best ASP.NET MVC framework/architecture and why?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture

There are a number of frameworks out there for building ASP.NET MVC applications (e.g. sharp architecture, etc...)?  In defining what a framework is, I'm thinking along the line of Ruby on Rails ... a stack of technologies that enable you to build all tiers of your application quickly, efficiently and with both testability and quality in mind.

So, in your *humble* opinions ... which is the best and why?

In particular I'm looking for an architecture that supports an RIA type front-end that takes full advantage of JQuery and/or ExtJs on the client.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the ASP.NET MVC framework is the best framework at the moment. The reason? Well, basically it is the only framework I've tried that allows you to depart completely from the WebForms methodology. Please note that I have tried a relatively few number of MVC frameworks and it's not like I'm saying that the ASP.NET MVC framework is perfect or anything.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC has the full force of the Microsoft .NET team behind it, which is hard to put a value on.

Comment: My question is what is the best ASP.NET MVC framework/architecture so ASP.NET MVC cannot be the answer :)  I'm thinking of things like Sharp Architecture, etc... Frameworks that utilize MVC but provide for a full system (e.g. domain layer, data access layer, IoC, etc...)